# hive: Get start and end dates based on a flag

Tags: sql, hive

I have table as below. I am trying to calculate days to purchase

```
Visitorid   date    Purch_flag
A           1-May       NULL
A           2-May       NULL
A           3-May        1  
B           1-May       NULL
B           2-May        1  
B           3-May       NULL
B           4-May        1  
C           1-May       NULL
```

Ideally I'd like to create a output table as below which has the start and end dates. There will be a new start date after purchase for the same visitorid

```
Visitorid   date    Purch_flag  start_date   end_date
A           1-May       NULL    1-May        3-May
A           2-May       NULL    1-May        3-May
A           3-May        1      1-May        3-May
B           1-May       NULL    1-May        2-May
B           2-May        1      1-May        2-May
B           3-May       NULL    3-May        4-May
B           4-May        1      3-May        4-May
C           1-May       NULL     NULL        NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with cumulative `max()` and `min()` window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(max(case when purch = 1 then date end) over (partition by visitorid order by date asc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),
                min(date) over (partition by visitorid)
               ) as start_date
       min(case when purch = 1 then date end) over (partition by visitorid order by date desc) as end_date
from t;
```

The end date is easier to explain.  It is the minimum of the date with a purchase on or after the given record.

The start date is the maximum of the date with a purchase *before* the given date.  If that is `NULL`, then it is the first date for the visitor.

Comment: getting this error FAILED: SemanticException End of a WindowFrame cannot be UNBOUNDED PRECEDING

Comment: @user7088181 . . . The Hive documentation explicitly states that this is valid syntax (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics).  The specific language is that the following syntax is allowed  "(ROWS | RANGE) BETWEEN (UNBOUNDED | [num]) PRECEDING AND ([num] PRECEDING | CURRENT ROW | (UNBOUNDED | [num]) FOLLOWING)"